# Is there a way to get the compiler version in haxe?

Tags: haxe

I am trying to make my own terminal using the haxe programming language. I am wondering if there is any way to get the haxe compiler version. I know that you can type `haxe -version` in the command prompt to get it but I need it in the code. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `haxe --version Print the current Haxe compiler version.`  (from the [docs](https://haxe.org/manual/compiler-usage.html))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a library you can use to get compiler version

https://lib.haxe.org/p/version/

or just use a macro from it

```
class Main {
    static public function main() {
        trace(StaticExtender.getHaxeCompilerVersion());
    }
}

class StaticExtender {
    public static macro function getHaxeCompilerVersion():haxe.macro.Expr {
        var proc_haxe_version = new sys.io.Process('haxe', [ '-version' ] );
        if (proc_haxe_version.exitCode() != 0) {
            throw("`haxe -version` failed: " + proc_haxe_version.stderr.readAll().toString());
        }
#if (haxe_ver >= 4)
        var haxe_ver = proc_haxe_version.stdout.readLine();
#else
        var haxe_ver = proc_haxe_version.stderr.readLine();
#end
        return macro $v{haxe_ver};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also available as a [compiler define](https://haxe.org/manual/compiler-usage-flags.html) which [can be read using macros](https://code.haxe.org/category/macros/get-compiler-define-value.html). `haxe_ver` seems to be available since 3.2 at least, you might want to check if you need to work with older compiler versions.

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        trace(getCompilerVersion());
    }

    static macro function getCompilerVersion() {
        return macro $v{haxe.macro.Context.definedValue("haxe_ver")};
    }
}
```

Comment: That's interesting. Macro from library returns 4.2.5, while compiler define value gives 4.205.  String vs. Double.

Comment: Indeed, a `haxe` define was introduced in which returns the version as semver, see [this issue](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/8302).